# For Azure Cosmos DB, is it possible to change from single region write to multi region write?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

As Cosmos DB cost extra for multi-region write, is it possible to start with single region write and upgrade to multi-region write at a later stage or will that require a database migration?

From the pricing information it looks like the multi-region write pricing kicks in even if you don't have any geo redundancy configured. So it looks like you either have to go with a high cost from the start, or choose to pay the price through a migration at a later stage. Is this a correct observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-region write functionality can be enable after a `single region` account has been created. This can be done via the Azure Portal or via Powershell: [Set up Azure Cosmos DB global distribution using the SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api)

This applies to the SQL(Core) API.

Powershell example: [Replicate an Azure Cosmos DB database account in multiple regions and configure failover priorities using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/scale-multiregion-powershell)

Comment: Those links refer to replication of data, not have multiple write regions. This link implies it has to be done at creation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#configure-multiple-write-regions